# SQL Server CE Application

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have written an application that I need to place on a SQL Server that pulls information from a SQL Server database and places it into a SQL Server CE database, however when I try to run it I get the error message that the dll's for SQL Server CE are missing.

Do I need to install SQL Server CE on the server or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the required DLL files with your app, no install required.

Comment: would I be required to 'install' the app on the server rather than just running an .exe?

Comment: No, you can simply copy the files, and run the .exe

Comment: I am getting the following error when the program attempts to make the first connection to SQLCE Database:

    An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (Exception from HRESULT: 0X8007000B)

Comment: You need to include both the x64 and x86 dll files, Please see my blog for detailed info